# Getting a onChange null error for my HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, null, onchange

This is my form below

```
<select name="catg" id="select">

    <option> Select..</option>
    <option value="stu">Uni Student</option>
    <option value="anothersstu">Student at another institution</option>
    <option value="staff">Uni Staff</option>
    <option value="other">other</option>

</select><br />

Student Number / Staff Number: <input type="text" name="ss" id="txt"/> <br />
```

This is my javascript:-

```
    document.getElementById('select').onchange{
    if(this.value=="stu"){
    document.getElementById('txt').maxLength=8;
    }else{
    document.getElementById('txt').removeAttribute('maxLength');
    }
     };
```

What its meant to do is, when the user selects Uni student from the select menu, the textbox for student number/ staff number has to be maxlength 8. It works in jsfiddle but not on the normal browser.

My error message on chrome:- Cannot read property 'onchange' of null

Any suggestions as to why its happening?

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code:**

```
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (this.value == "stu") {
        document.getElementById('txt').maxLength = 8;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('txt').removeAttribute('maxLength');
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null - get that error now.

Comment: in all browser or chrome only ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `function` keyword

Try this

```
document.getElementById('select').onchange = function(){
    if(this.value=="stu"){
    document.getElementById('txt').maxLength=8;
    }else{
    document.getElementById('txt').removeAttribute('maxLength');
    }
     };
```

Here's the Fiddle link to try - http://jsfiddle.net/pcJ7W/

Comment: works in the fiddle, Do you have another element with id=select ? Can you try changing the id and then run?